# Apps, Extensions and scripts cannot be added from this website

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app, crx

I'm trying to add the Rapid Interface Builder extension to chrome using the `rib.crx` file I downloaded from https://01.org/rapid-interface-builder/downloads/2012/rib-preview-1-chrome-extension

Unfortunately, every time I open the `crx` file with chrome I get the following error:

> Apps, Extensions and scripts cannot be added from this website.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Looks like some good answers are given for crx files, anybody know how address this issue with userscripts (e.g. example.userscript.js)?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Instead of opening the file, you have to: extract it (crx are zip files), then visit `chrome://extensions`, enable developer mode, and `load unpacked extension`.

The reason for this is: lots of people try to abuse chrome apps/extensions to install nasty applications to your browser.  So Chrome tries to make it impossible to automatically side-load these apps without you making sure that is really what you want to do.

So.. typical caveats of installing software apply when using this approach.

Comment: I'm unable to extract the file - it's not an option, I'm able to compress it.  I'm using Windows 8 if that helps with answering.

Comment: The "Load unpacked extension" option is not a great solution for Windows any more, because of a nagging popup, see http://crbug.com/337734.

Comment: I got it.  Had to open it with WinRar to extract it.  I also had to edit the manifest.json file to include ""manifest_version": 2," in it's contents.

Comment: on macOS this didn't work when I renamed it to *.zip and tried extracting with Finder but it did work on the command line with `unzip Extension.crx -d Extension`

Comment: in my case it is downloading `.js` file instead of `.crx` file? what should i do?

Answer (score 26):

You can now also just drag-and-drop the .crx file onto the chrome://extensions page and it will install, too.

**Edit 2019-01-10:** Make sure to enable Developer mode for extensions. If this was not enabled, refresh the chrome://extensions page after enabling it.

**Edit 2018-08-24:** This works on Windows, too.

<strike>**Edit**:
This doesn't work on Windows. Verified on OSX and ChromeOS. From what I've read, this will work on Linux, too.~</strike>

Comment: Have you tried it with .crx files not packed by your Chrome install?

Comment: @Xan yes, I packed in on OSX stable (44.0.2403.157) and then dragged and dropped onto ChromeOS stable (44.0.2403.155). However, I get the disabled warning on Windows stable (44.0.2403.157 m). I'll edit my answer to reflect that this works on everything except Windows (pretty certain it'll work on Linux).

Comment: The above answer is rather old. Just tested it on windows and it works now.

Comment: It doesn't work for me. I still get the following error when I drop-and-drop the .crx file: `Apps, Extensions and scripts cannot be added from this website.`. The only way I could get it to install was to unpack the .crx file first.

Comment: @DanStevens sounds like a problem on your end. Just tested on OS X and Windows 10 with Chrome 71.0.3578.98. You have to have Developer mode on and be in the Extensions page. I'll edit my answer to include the Developer mode requirement.

Comment: I found that after enabling Developer mode, I had to refresh the extensions page before it would accept the extension. If I just enabled Developer mode and not refresh I would still get the error.

Comment: wow I was trying everything! just had to refresh lol

Answer (score 9):

(I initially experienced the same problem you described.*)
This solution worked for me in Windows 10 (build th1511) x64:

1. Open Chrome as you normally would.
2. Go to the "Extensions" page (chrome://extensions; *or* click Menu button at top right corner → From 'More tools' drop down menu select 'Extensions').
3. Drag and drop the .crx file onto the extensions page in Chrome -onto the list of extensions.
   You should see a dialog stating "Drop here to install". This must be present. *(If you do NOT see this, reposition your mouse - it may be too far to the side of the page.)*

It should load successfully and you should see the extension in the list immediately afterward.

*I received the same error you described when attempting to load the .crx file (packed extension) by right-clicking/double-clicking it and selecting "Open With" "Chrome", and by dragging/dropping the file onto a regular webpage in Chrome.

Comment: Yeah, dropping on Chrome or even in the extensions page wasn't enough--as suggested in the answer, it needed to be in the area showing "drop here to install"

Comment: Works great. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

In the Extensions page, just enable Developer mode. From there you can drag and drop any .crx file there and installation prompt will follow suit.

[image: Developer mode turned on]

Answer (score 3):

Open Chrome with this parameter **--enable-easy-off-store-extension-install**, then go to extensions and enable Developer mode. Now you can install `.crx` files without any problem.

Answer (score 0):

go on extension, and your first step is on developer mode, 2 step update extensions, and last drop IDM extension file on google chrome.